# Unable to pass parameter in AuthorizeNet Sample Code for PHP

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am integrating AuthorizeNet Sample code provided in their Github Account for PHP platform. Code is working fine, But I am unable to pass following parmeters :-

1) Customer Name 
2) Customer Phone number
3) Customer Email address
4) Order Id
5) Order Description

I am using following code for making transaction. However you can view full code from their Github account as well

Github URL : https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/PaymentTransactions/authorize-credit-card.php

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
  use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;
  define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");
  function authorizeCreditCard($amount){
    // Common setup for API credentials
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCode\Constants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCode\Constants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);
    $refId = 'ref' . time();
    // Create the payment data for a credit card
    $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
    $creditCard->setCardNumber("4111111111111111");
    $creditCard->setExpirationDate("1226");
    $creditCard->setCardCode("123");
    $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
    $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);
    //create a transaction
    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType( "authOnlyTransaction"); 
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount($amount);
    $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
    $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId( $refId);
    $request->setTransactionRequest( $transactionRequestType);
    $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
    if ($response != null)
    {
      if($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == \SampleCode\Constants::RESPONSE_OK)
      {
        $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();

          if ($tresponse != null && $tresponse->getMessages() != null)   
        {
          echo " Transaction Response code : " . $tresponse->getResponseCode() . "\n";
          echo " Successfully created a transaction with Auth code : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
          echo " TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
          echo " Code : " . $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getCode() . "\n"; 
            echo " Description : " . $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getDescription() . "\n";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Transaction Failed \n";
          if($tresponse->getErrors() != null)
          {
            echo " Error code  : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode() . "\n";
            echo " Error message : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText() . "\n";            
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        echo "Transaction Failed \n";
        $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();

        if($tresponse != null && $tresponse->getErrors() != null)
        {
          echo " Error code  : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode() . "\n";
          echo " Error message : " . $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText() . "\n";                      
        }
        else
        {
          echo " Error code  : " . $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getCode() . "\n";
          echo " Error message : " . $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getText() . "\n";
        }
      }      
    }
    else
    {
      echo  "No response returned \n";
    }

    return $response;
  }
  if(!defined('DONT_RUN_SAMPLES'))
    authorizeCreditCard( 23.32);
?>
```

Comment: I've fixed the issue and make some changes in the code. Please find below link for updated code.

Code URL : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2bd70562f4b3ee8d77a42078cc1cf3b1